# Which Networkx graphs could be used?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I have a mixed nature data. The data has nodes, edges and communities all mixed together and I want to plot them into a graph and visualize them to understand the patterns. I am looking for something like the attached picture. [image] The degree is not known here. I did check the [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/index.html) documentation but could not find anything close to what I am looking for. This is a un directed and non directional graph. I could separate the data and plot them into different formats but when it comes to real time separation could not be possible. The data comes like a flow and those independent nodes can or might also form communities in future data occurrences so cannot separate them.

The data patterns are something like below

```
2344
2424 3535
2445
2434 5525 3454 4335 2355
2342 3453 5555 2425 5255
3423 2525
2344
5234 3455 4555
```

The nodes, edges and communities show repeating behavior in time intervals

Answer (score 2):

You can use the methods/functions `add_nodes_from()` and `add_edges_from()` found [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.add_nodes_from.html#add-nodes-from) and [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.add_edges_from.html#networkx.Graph.add_edges_from) from the standard undirected graph class of NetworkX. This way you can create your graph step by step as the data flow comes. 
All you have to do is to convert the data into the correct format and pass it "line by line" into the two functions. They will only add nodes or edges to your graph if they are not already there. `add_edges_from()` also adds new nodes of the added edges, but that obviously doesn't work for your data lines with only one node, because one nodes doesn't form an edge.
I would suggest doing something like this :

```
import networkx as nx

# create empty graph
G = nx.Graph()

# read data
data = ...

# assuming you can acces the lines of your data through an iterator, add them to the graph
for line in data:
    G.add_nodes_from(line)
    # get the number of nodes in the data line
    number_of_nodes = get_number_of_nodes(line)
    if number_of_nodes > 1:
        # get edgelist from data line and add it to the graph
        edgelist = get_edgelist(line)
        G.add_edges_from(edgelist)
```

There is of course some work left for the "converter functions" `get_number_of_nodes()` and `get_edgelist()`, but it's a start ...